# Could not find a part of the path (Write file html)

Tags: c#

I need to  create html file and save to  drive C:/TMP after i public it error
Could not find a part of the path 'C:\TMP\test.html'

I have the following code

```
string fileName = @"C:\\TMP\\test.html";     
        using (FileStream fs = File.Create(fileName))
        {
            using (StreamWriter w = new StreamWriter(fs, Encoding.UTF8))
            { 
                 w.WriteLine("<!DOCTYPE html>");
                 w.WriteLine("<html>");
                 w.WriteLine("<head>");
                 w.WriteLine("<title>PChart</title>");
                 w.WriteLine("</p>");
                 w.WriteLine("</body>");
                 w.WriteLine("</html>");
            }
        }
```

Comment: Do you have test.html file in the path?

Comment: Does C:\TMP exist ?

Comment: when i run http://localhost/ not error after i public it error

Comment: instead of c drive try other drive

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure the directory exists ? Put `Directory.CreateDirectory` in our code:

```
string fileName = @"C:\\TMP\\BlaBla\\test.html";     
Directory.CreateDirectory(Path.GetDirectoryName(fileName));
using (FileStream fs = File.Create(fileName))
{
    using (StreamWriter w = new StreamWriter(fs, Encoding.UTF8))
    {
        w.WriteLine("<!DOCTYPE html>");
        w.WriteLine("<html>");
        w.WriteLine("<head>");
        w.WriteLine("<title>PChart</title>");
        w.WriteLine("</p>");
        w.WriteLine("</body>");
        w.WriteLine("</html>");
    }
}
```

I tested, for me it works

Comment: So it's a permission issue, check if you have right to write on this folder

Comment: Thank you everybody for help.

Comment: I tried  to fix error : 'C:\TMP' is denied :I found that this drive  is a server  not my computer how to set driver C to my computer

Answer (score 0):

Hi pls try using below code. If there is no file It will create. But path should be correct.

```
string path = @"D:\\TMP\\test.html";
            using (StreamWriter w = System.IO.File.AppendText(path))
            {
                w.WriteLine("<!DOCTYPE html>");
                w.WriteLine("<html>");
                w.WriteLine("<head>");
                w.WriteLine("<title>PChart</title>");
                w.WriteLine("</p>");
                w.WriteLine("</body>");
                w.WriteLine("</html>");
            }
```